What is the maximum number of edges such a planar graph can have?
In my research, I encountered the following problem with a planar graph.
A planar graph with $n$ vertices satisfies the following four conditions:
(1) Every vertex has a degree of at least 4,
(2) each face is either a triangle or a quadrilateral,
(3) no two triangles share a common edge.
What is the maximum number of edges (on the order $n$) this planar graph can have?
We know that we want as many triangular faces as possible. A  trivial bound is
$3n−6$, but such a graph would necessarily violate condition (3).

Let $f$ be the number of faces, and $f_3$ be the number of triangles. Each edge of a triangle must be involved in a face of size at least $4$, so $$3f_3\leq 4(f-f_3)$$
So:
$$f_3\leq \frac{4}{7}f$$
with equality when all the non-triangle faces are $4$-faces, and that each $4$ face is surrounded by triangles.
Moreover, by double-counting:
$$2m \geq 3f_3+4(f-f_3) = 4f-f3\geq 4f-\frac{4}{7}f = \frac{24}{7}f$$
By Euler formula:
$$m-n+2 =f \leq \frac{7}{12}m$$
So:
$$m\leq \frac{12}{5}(n-2)$$
This bound is attained for example by the cuboctahedral graph.
There is also a tiling attaining this bound: Take a square tiling, and replace half of the squares by a cuboctahedral graph.
